# open file outside of project in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Would specifically like to edit `/etc/hosts` without leaving the Intellij window. How can I open this file while working on some arbitrary project in Intellij?

Comment: Menu | File | Open?

Comment: Thanks @Meo. This indeed answers my question.If I could ask for more, is there any way to achieve the functionality of Shift-Cmd-O (Shift-Ctrl-O on Windows)? Where we are able to type the path of some file in our project and open it? Menu | File | Open is correct, but it opens a mouse-centric dialog for choosing a file. Wouldn't it be nice if we could just type `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: You can write in that dialog too.

Comment: Very good, thanks @Meo. I do wish that we could do all of this without a mouse. I do find it necessary to click "File | Open" to get it started.

Comment: And my apologies if this question seems inane. I just want to work as effectively as the IDE lets me.

Comment: Then use a shortcut.

Answer (score 7):

Clicking on the File menu (Left hand corner) then clicking Open does the trick, just like most applications.

To set a shortcut for that File Open click you can click on File then settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) and then under Keymap search for File Open. Right click open and you should see the add shortcut dialog. I'm a bit surprised there isn't a default shortcut for this.

Comment: Don't drag it in the window, will just close the file (pycharm 2018.3), the File|Open worked

Answer (score 1):

Dragging file to Pycharm or using File|Open are not working anymore with the latest Pycharm. You might want to launch LightEditor of Pycharm instead.

```bash
pycharm -e /etc/hosts
```